# Spring data JPA one to Many / Many to one not inserting/updating details in database

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Am doing one small activity of Teach and address relationship for one to many and in address block there will be one to one relationship between country, district, tahasil etc. Whenever am hitting api and to save it it's not updating or inserting Address in address table.
Detail is

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "teachers")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "user_id")
public class Teacher extends User {

@Size(min = 3, max = 50)
    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Size(min = 3, max = 50)
    @Column(name = "middle_name")
    private String middleName;

    @Size(min = 3, max = 50)
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy = "teacher")
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Set<Address> addresses = new HashSet<>(0);

   Getter Setter...
}
```

Then Address Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "address")
public class Address {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "address_id")
    private Long addressId;

    @ManyToOne (fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    @JsonBackReference
    private Teacher teacher;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "country_id", referencedColumnName = "country_id")
    private Country country;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "state_id", referencedColumnName = "state_id")
    private State state;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "district_id", referencedColumnName = "district_id")
    private District district;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "tahasil_id", referencedColumnName = "tahasil_id")
    private Tahasil tahasil;

    @Column(name = "line_one")
    private String lineOne;

    @Column(name = "line_two")
    private String lineTwo;

    @Column(name = "landmark")
    private String landmark;

    @Column(name = "pincode")
    private Integer pincode;

    public Country getCountry() {
        return country;
    }
    Other Getter Setter
```

The Country example same to state, district and tahasil

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "countries", uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "country_name" }) })
public class Country {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "country_id")
    private Long countryId;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(min = 3, max = 50)
    @Column(name = "country_name")
    private String countryName;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "country")
    private Address address;

    Getter Setter
```

Finally in controller am doing like

```
    Optional<Teacher> teacher = teacherRepo.findByUserId(id);

        if (!teacher.isPresent())
            return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();

        teacher.get().setUserId(id);
        teacher.get().setFirstName(teacherUpdateForm.getFirstName());
        teacher.get().setMiddleName(teacherUpdateForm.getMiddleName());
        teacher.get().setLastName(teacherUpdateForm.getLastName()); 
        teacher.get().setAddresses(teacherUpdateForm.getAddresses());
        userRepository.save(teacher.get());
```

Tried so may ways by referring multiple sites and readouts, but still not able to see any insert or update to address table. Please help me to get my mistake.

Regards,
Chetan

Answer (score 0):

You need to cascade the persist of the Teacher entity.

Update the definition of the attribute Address inside the Teacher entity:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy = "teacher", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JsonManagedReference
private Set<Address> addresses = new HashSet();
```

You can play with the cascade type value as you want.

Comment: Excellent @stoica-raul, at least moved one step ahead, but now able to see SQL constraint saying Column 'user_id' cannot be null, my assumption is in address table whenever it makes entry it should get user_id automatically from teachers table, which is default mapping we made

Comment: Can you please show me the definition of the table structure that the Address entity has? Also, paste here the error?